# How to extract each digit from int without using stack or array? (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, int, modulo

I have an assignment where I'm suppose to print a specific code when a number is entered such as 90621. I am suppose to extract that number in order and print the code ex: extract digit 9 print code --> extract 0 (in order).

The thing is I only figured out how to extract the numbers in reverse order ( ex: extracting 1 first and then 2 for 90621) and I'm not sure how to do it in order. I have seen some post on here where people convert the digit to a string, but I can't do that since one of the function I'm calling takes an int as a parameter. We've also only covered basics such as loops and if functions so far, so I'm not sure how to use stack or array.

This is my code for extracting the numbers and printing the code so far:

```
string barCode(int zip){
    string result;
    int n;
    while (zip > 0){
        n = zip % 10;
        result += codeForDigit(n);
        zip = zip / 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Some info on the functions: 
 - The function **codeForDigit(int digit)** takes one digit and returns the code for that digit.
 - `barCode(int zip)` Which returns an entire bar code by breaking the number into individual digits, encoding that digit, and adding it to the string return value.

Comment: Have you gone over recursion?  iterating plus a stack == recursion.

Comment: We've gone over basic recursion, but I am not familiar with how to push the numbers onto a stack.

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2df9da8fc9cba815) is a little example of how you can go "backwards".

Comment: Basically have got result in the reverse order right? Why not just reverse it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way is through recursion. In fact, it is quite elegant. You can write something like this:

```
string barCode(int zip)
{
    if (zip <= 0) return "";
    return (barCode(zip / 10) + codeForDigit(zip % 10));
}
```

Basically, you're using the call stack as your stack for storing the previous strings. It's also a minimal way of writing this function.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the string result after you're done with conversion to char each digit:

```
std::string barCode(int zip){
    std::string result;
    while(zip > 0){
        result += zip % 10 + '0';
        zip /= 10;
    }

    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());     
    return result;
}


int main(){
    std::cout << barCode(245) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```
string barCode(int zip)
{
    string result;
    if(zip <=0) return "";

    //Find 10s in zip
    int i=zip/10;

    int nTens = 0;
    while( i<=0)
    {
        i = i/10;
        nTens++;
    }

    int n;
    for (int j=0; j<=nTens ; j++)
    {
        n = zip / pow(10, (nTens-j));
        result += codeForDigit(n);
        zip = zip - n * pow(10, (nTens-j))
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way is transform the number in a string and the iterates over it:

```
int zip = 123456789;
std::string digits = std::to_string(zip);
std::string barcode;
int d=0;

for (auto it=digits.begin(); it != digits.end();it++)
{
    d= int(*it);
    barcode.push_back(codeForDigit(d-'0'));
}
```